# Magento 2 : Disable Caching for the Block or cacheable false

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache, disable

I have tried to get update value without caching block.

I have tried all below code,but they are not work.

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}

 $this->addData([
        'cache_lifetime' => 0,
        'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Store\Model\Store::CACHE_TAG, \Magento\Cms\Model\Block::CACHE_TAG]]);


 public function getCacheLifetime()
{ 
 return null;
}

$block->setCacheLifetime(0);
```

How to disable the cache for block?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share which block you want to remove from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the relevant `block` or `referenceBlock` node in your layout XML file and set the `cacheable` attribute to `false`.

It should be noted that this will *DISABLE* FPC for *ALL* pages that the layout XML in question applies to. Looking at the cache tags in your code this looks like it might be all CMS pages, which would not be ideal.

What is it you are trying to avoid caching? It may be better to achieve the required functionality by utilising [Private Content](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/).

*If this is the correct answer please mark it "accepted" as it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find the answer.*

Comment: I can not use cacheable=false ,is there other solution ?

Comment: Is there a reason for that @JigsParmar?
What is it you are trying to prevent being cached?

Comment: above code tried to prevent cache.